# Is there a way to check if an ActiveRecord attribute is serialized?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

```rb
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :emails, Array
end
```

I need to know if `emails` attribute is serialized.
I expected to find a method like `serialized?` or `serialized_by?`, but I couldn't find it.

Is there a way to check this?

Comment: It seems that there used to be `serialized_attributes` method, now deprecated without replacement: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/15704